# Copy the contents of existing page to another page with different name in wordpress without using any plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am new in WordPress. In my WordPress application having one page named "Retail". I want to create new page named "Website" with the same content of "Retail" page. I copied content and paste in to new page editor and saved. But some CSS problem is there. I think css file is missing kind. How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Also say what error you are facing. Your question is not clear without issue how to any  one give you solution. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

We cannot find the problem without any real information. However you can check if any of the following issues occurs:

1. You use a theme which let you add custom CSS rules in specific page. You might have a settings button in the page where you add it. In that case, you need to copy that as well.
2. You need to check your CSS files and see if the styling rules are applied for a specific page. It could be like `.page-id-662` or `.pageid-662`
3. The last you could check is the `functions.php` file in case you enqueue a styling CSS file on specific pages as well.

Answer (score 0):

What did you do exactly?
Created a new page in the Wordpress backend and copied the contents of "Retail?
Or put on a whole new Wordpress website and copy the "Retail" page there? 
And please give an example of what went wrong in the design. Can you possibly specify the HTML code of an element with a design error?

Comment: Actually I created a new page in the backend and copied the contents of retails page to that newly created page

Comment: The original text may have been css codes or similar. added, which refer only euf this page, possibly with the number of the page. This is of course also new on the new page. Generally included css files are always available for the entire blog.
Can you switch from visual to text in the top right corner? The html view is displayed. Search for the unfavorable elements and search from there on.